# Resize Javascript Element to Browser Size

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript adplayer script that I want to dynamically resize when the browser window size changes. How should I do this?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rnd = window.rnd || Math.floor(Math.random()*10e6);
    var pid155420 = window.pid155420 || rnd;
    var plc155420 = window.plc155420 || 0;
    var abkw = window.abkw || '';
    var absrc =         'http://servedby.myexampledomain.com/adserve/;ID=162421;size=468x60;setID=155420;type=js;kw='        +abkw+';pid='+pid155420+';place='+(plc155420++)+';rnd='+rnd+'';
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="'+absrc+'" type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>');
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to the window.resize event. In jQuery, it's the following.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var currentWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    var currentWindowHeight = $(window).height();
    // do stuff with these variables
});
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Answer (score 0):

Since someone already provided the jQuery answer without any indication jQuery was actually being used ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setShtuff(){
        var rnd = window.rnd || Math.floor(Math.random()*10e6);
        var pid155420 = window.pid155420 || rnd;
        var plc155420 = window.plc155420 || 0;
        var abkw = window.abkw || '';
        var absrc = 'http://servedby.myexampledomain.com/adserve/;ID=162421;size=468x60;setID=155420;type=js;kw='        +abkw+';pid='+pid155420+';place='+(plc155420++)+';rnd='+rnd+'';
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="'+absrc+'" type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>');
    }

    window.onload = setShtuff;
    window.onresize = setShtuff;
</script>
```

[You can see a more complete explanation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize)

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the handler to install the handler, that means you're assigning the result of calling `functionName()` to `window.onresize`

Comment: updated the example to give more context than just the simple one I had before. put the JS provided into a function, call that function both onload and onresize.